# How do I use jQuery to create a bookmark-able hash?

Tags: jquery, html, fragment-identifier, browser-state

I have a single URL I am using as an image gallery. At this URL is a thumbs `div` (I'm only showing four thumbs for the sake of brevity):

```
 <div id="thumbs">
 <img src="graphics/thumbs/01.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb objects" id="project01" />
 <img src="graphics/thumbs/08.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb web" id="project08" />
 <img src="graphics/thumbs/14.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb freehand" id="project14"/>
 <img src="graphics/thumbs/04.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb freehand objects" id="project04" /></div>
```

And an empty `div` called `#content`:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and a hidden `div` called `#preload`:

```
 <div id="preload">
<span id="project01_content"><img src="graphics/010.jpg" /></span>
<span id="project02_content"><img src="graphics/022.jpg" /><img src="graphics/021.jpg" /><img src="graphics/023.jpg" /><img src="graphics/020.jpg" /></span>
<span id="project03_content"><img src="graphics/030.jpg" width="450" height="600" /><img src="graphics/031.jpg" width="450" height="600" /></span>
<span id="project04_content"><img src="graphics/040.jpg" width="775" height="600" /><img src="graphics/041.jpg" width="775" height="600" /></span></div>
```

My jQuery uses the ID of the clicked thumbnail to `clone()` the images from the corresponding `span` and drop them into `#content` using the `html()` method. It works great. Now, I'd like to return to `mysite.com/#project01` and have `#content` already filled with Project 01.

How can I give each image a hashed URL that will call up the same jQuery state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just perform a click on that thumb as soon as the page loads and your current code should execute, like this:

```
$(function() {
  if(window.location.hash.indexOf('project') > -1)
    $(window.location.hash).click();
});
```

This uses the [`window.location.hash` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) which would be `"#project01"` in your example URL...so it's already an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), we're just checking that it's a hash we care about, then using that selector to fire a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).  Just make sure this runs *after* your current click handler for the thumbs is bound.